# Get Latest Version of Folder from TFS, using Powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-2.0, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to "**Get Latest Version**" of a particular folder from TFS, using Powershell.

I have installed the TFS Snappin, and have been using TFS Power Tools cmdlets in PowerShell (such as Get-TfsChildItem and Select-TfsItem etc) [[How do I set up TFS PowerShell Snapin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050689/how-do-i-set-up-tfs-powershell-snapin) ], and have gone through their documentation (which I didn't find explanatory enough!).

Confused, on the exact cmdlet to use, when I am trying to get the latest version of an entire Folder structure from TFS, that is mapped to my local drive (*and not just a changeset or ChildItem*).

Example : 
Tfs Path - $/APD-RepairSolutions/Main/Database

Mapped  path - D:\TFS\APD-RepairSolutions/Main/Database.

I want a code, that would iteratively get the latest version of the entire folder *Database*,( that has number of tables,stored procedures etc.)

I am using ..

```
PS D:\Tfs\APD-RepairSolutions\Main\Database> $server=Get-TfsServer -Name http://tfs:8080/tfs

PS D:\Tfs\APD-RepairSolutions\Main\Database> Get-TfsChangeset -Recurse -Server $Server
```

Not helping my case - as it is only returning the latest changeset in the current directory.

Comment: did you tried  TFS Power Tools cmdlets ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get latest (`tf get`) use `Update-TfsWorkspace`.

`Get-TfsChangeset` is the equivalent of `tf changeset`.

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha! with Update-TFSWorskpace. Has some helpful parameters as well. *-Items* is used to specify the exact items you want to update.

```
PS D:\Tfs\APD-RepairSolutions\Main>Update-TFSWorkspace -All -Overwrite -Force -Recurse -Items .\Database
```

The Workspace is replaced with updated versions of items. Thanks @Kmoraz!

Comment: I just want to say the switch is _-Item_ and not _-Items_.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use the TFS API instead, you can use the [Workspace.Get Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139308(v=vs.120).aspx):

```
# Load the TFS assemblies
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
$ws = $vcServer.QueryWorkspaces("<WORKSPACENAME>", $null, $null);

# Specify properties of intended workspace get
$recursionType = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.RecursionType]::Full
$latestVersion = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionSpec]::Latest
$getOptions = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.GetOptions]::GetAll

# Get what I want!
$ws.Get("$/Remote/Folder", $latestVersion, $recursionType, $getOptions)
```

Would be a good idea to replace the nulls with your domain login and computer name when [Querying Workspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138991(v=vs.120).aspx).

Comment: This is great! For reference, changing GetOptions to Overwrite seems to match "Get Latest Version" in Visual Studio:
....`.GetOptions]::Overwrite`